# Do I have to declare the array of UIViewControllers as lazy var when using UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

I would like to call a function of one of the subviewcontrollers inside my MainPageViewController (which is an UIPageViewController), but I cannot do that due to viewControllerList property function.

```
lazy var viewControllerList: [UIViewController] = {
    let vc1 = BasicBreathingViewController()
    let vc2 = RotatingBreathingViewController()
    return [vc1, vc2]
}()
```

I would like to access vc1 and vc2 outside the function to be able to call for example the vc1.animate() function.

I have already tried to make vc1 and vc2 global variables, but then the MainPageViewController crashes.

Comment: Your entire approach is wrong. Do not make a list of view controller instances. If you need to talk to a view controller, it should be an actual view controller already in the interface, and you talk to it by getting a reference to it. Either the view controller you want to talk to is currently your page view controller's child or it isn't; if it is, talk to it directly by way of the page view controller's `viewControllers` property, and if it isn't, there is nothing to do, as the view controller does not exist.

Comment: How can I use viewControllers property inside the MainPageViewController to be able to access the child viewcontroller's function? I tried playing around with viewControllers?.first and viewControllers[currentIndex], but no luck.

Comment: To avoid crossed wires, when you say Child View controllers, do you mean a sub-view controller that presents some UI as part of your MainPageViewController, or do you mean view controllers that are opened by the MainPage as view controllers in their own right?

Comment: Well, if the first v.c. is a BasicBreathingViewController, then this would be `thePageViewController.viewControllers?.first as? BasicBreathingViewController`.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much! :)